# iOS (but not OSX) browsers change curly apostrophe to straight

Tags: html, ios, macos, punctuation

All my iOS browsers (Safari, Chrome, Firefox, and Opera) take it upon themselves to change curly apostrophes that are followed by an ‘s’ to typographically incorrect straight apostrophes. Even stranger is that it does *not* make this change if the apostrophe is not followed by an ‘s’ (screen capture [curly vs. straight apostrophes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5UYi.png) shows an example of each.)

[Codepen example](https://codepen.io/john_skowronski/pen/VKzxjy)

I can fix this problem by inserting a Word Joiner character (HTML entity `&#8288;`) on either side of the `&rsquo;` character.

Here is the HTML that *should* work:

```
<li>Delta Airlines&rsquo; Sky magazine</li>
<li>Delta Shuttle&rsquo;s Shuttle Sheet magazine</li>
```

And here is the HTML that actually *does* work:

```
<li>Delta Airlines&#8288;&rsquo; Sky magazine</li>
<li>Delta Shuttle&#8288;&rsquo;&#8288;s Shuttle Sheet magazine</li>
```

None of my OSX desktop browsers exhibits this odd behavior. (UPDATE: I *was* using OSX v10.7.5—current version of OSX *does* exhibit the same behavior as iOS) <strike>In other words, in OSX I can omit the Word Joiner characters and the curly apostrophe displays correctly with or without the trailing ‘s’.</strike> And yes, I am explicitly declaring `<meta charset="utf-8">`.

So I can work around this, but I shouldn’t have to; it’s a pain to have to be ever-vigilant about this every time I use an apostrophe, and it makes the HTML a bit more cluttered and obscure. Does anyone know what’s going on here?

Comment: I added the rendered output to your question and I see the expected curly apostrophe on both an iPhone running iOS 10 and an iPad running iOS 9 in addition to my Mac - all using Safari. Perhaps stack overflow is changing something a bit. Might help to post a link to a real URL that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @rmaddy—I thought there was no point in posting rendered output, as the problem does not occur in desktop browsers, but only in iOS. That's why I attached an iPhone screenshot. I'm running iOS 9.3.5, so maybe they fixed this in iOS 10.

Comment: Plenty of people use SO on iOS devices. I do it often.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this is a problem with the Alegreya Sans font itself, not any browser or OS:

https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/27606/why-does-libreoffice-replace-alegreya-sans-curly-quote-with-its-regular-quote/

According to the final respondent, the type foundry fixed the problem in 2014, but my site is linking to it as a GoogleFont, so it's not fixed here in 2016. I guess I'll just have to live with my "Word Joiner" kludge.